# What is the difference between a Roster Group and Multi-User Chat Rooms in Smack (XMPP library)?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'am new to XMPP protocol and I'am working on a chat application in android using smack library. I'am stuck in creating group chat. I want to create a group, add members to it and send message to all members of a group (like whatsApp group). When searching about group chat i got two things

1. Group
   : creating group using `createGroup(String name)` method present in `Roster` class.
2. Multi User chat : creating a Multi-user chat using `MultiUserChatManager` .

I'am getting confused regarding **what is Group** and **what is Multi-User chat**? Can anyone explain the basic difference between them and which one should i use and also how to send message to everyone in group ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Roster Group**
   created using `createGroup(String name)` method present in `Roster` class

   It's merely a group for your contacts, mostly for visual purposes in an IM client. It's like creating groups in phone contacts.
2. **Multi-User Chat Rooms** 
   created using `MultiUserChatManager`

   `MultiUserChat` is used for creating chat rooms and adding various users as member of chat room. This should be used for group(Chat room with some members) messaging. This has nothing to do with Roster Group.

Comment: Hi Harish , Could you please explain about 'Groups' rather than roster groups it is presents under users/Groups category?